# Recurrently shows Odoo Server Error while printing Excel sheet on lines or notebooks in Odoo

Tags: python, excel, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to generate an Excel report using openpyxl in Odoo 10 but recurrently shows:

> Odoo Server Error while printing excel sheet on lines or notebooks

Here is the piece of Python code below:

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):      
        if vals.get('gstr2_file'):
            dirpath_gstr2 = os.environ.get('HOME') or os.getcwd()
            abs_filepath_gstr2 = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath_gstr2, vals['filename_gstr2']))
            with open(abs_filepath_gstr2, 'w') as file:
                file.write(base64.b64decode(vals.get('gstr2_file')))
            #vals['excel_file'] = False
        res = super(BiExcel, self).create(vals)
        return res

    @api.multi
    def generate_gstr2(self,vals):
        for file in self:
            dirpath_gstr2 = os.environ.get('HOME') or os.getcwd()
            base_path_gstr2 = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath_gstr2, file.filename_gstr2))
            if os.path.isfile(base_path_gstr2):
                wb_gstr2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(base_path_gstr2,data_only=True)
                sheet_name_gstr2 = wb_gstr2.get_sheet_names()
                sheet_gstr2 = wb_gstr2.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name_gstr2[0])
                field_gstr2_obj = self.env['ir.model.fields']
                excel_gstr2_heading = []
                for excel_row_gstr2 in range(1, sheet_gstr2.max_row+1):
                    if not sheet_gstr2.cell(row=excel_row_gstr2, column=1).value:
                        break
                    excel_gstr2_data = {}
                    excel_gstr2_data_field = []
                    excel_column_gstr2 =1
                    for excel_column_gstr2 in range(1, sheet_gstr2.max_column+1):
                        if excel_row_gstr2 == 1:
                            heading_gstr2 = sheet_gstr2.cell(row=excel_row_gstr2, column=excel_column_gstr2).value
                            #raise UserError(_(str((heading_gstr2))))
                            domain_gstr2 = [('field_description','=',heading_gstr2),('model' ,'=', 'bi.gstr2')]
                            field_gstr2_id = field_gstr2_obj.search(domain_gstr2)
                            excel_gstr2_data_field.append(field_gstr2_id.name)
                            excel_gstr2_heading.append(heading_gstr2)
                            #raise UserError(_(str((excel_gstr2_data_field))))
                        else:
                            domain_gstr2 = [('field_description','=',excel_gstr2_heading[excel_column_gstr2-1]),('model' ,'=', 'bi.gstr2')] 
                            field_gstr2_id = field_gstr2_obj.search(domain_gstr2)
                            cell_gstr2_value = sheet_gstr2.cell(row=excel_row_gstr2, column=excel_column_gstr2).value
                            #raise UserError(_(str((cell_gstr2_value))))
                            #if field_gstr2_id:
                            excel_gstr2_data[field_gstr2_id.name]=cell_gstr2_value
                            excel_gstr2_data['gstr2_id']=file.id
                    excel_column_gstr2 = excel_column_gstr2 + 1
                    if excel_gstr2_data:
                        #raise UserError(_(str((excel_gstr2_data))))
                        self.env['bi.gstr2'].create(excel_gstr2_data)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Have look to your Odoo log, and find the error log. I believe, there is information more than what you told.